# To create a Graph OrientDB with a csv file

Tags: csv, orientdb

I'm new to the orientdb, I want to create a graph from a csv file. the csv file defines the connections of my vertices. This is my code but I have an error java.lang.NullPointerException.

the format of my csv file is:
source, weight, dest

Can someone help me?

```
package OrientDB;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
```

Comment: Please provide more information

Comment: post your full code and orientdb version

Answer (score 1):

When you read the lines of Libro1.cvs you need to skip the first line (source, weight, dest) , otherwise v1 and v2 will be null and you will get NullPointerException when `Edge eLives = orientDBGraph.addEdge(null, v1, v2, "connected");`is executed

**UPDATE**

I created the database with the class connected (extends E).
I used  this csv

```
source, weight, dest
1,10,2
2,30,4
```

with this code

```
public class CSVReader {

private static final String ORIENT_DB_PATH = "localhost/40005113";
static OrientGraphNoTx orientDBGraph;
static OrientGraphFactory factory;

public static void main(String[] args) {


    factory = new OrientGraphFactory("remote:"+ORIENT_DB_PATH);
    orientDBGraph = factory.getNoTx();

    HashMap<String, Vertex> nodes = new HashMap<String, Vertex>();

    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        Vertex v = orientDBGraph.addVertex("class:V");
        v.setProperty("vertexID", i+"");
        nodes.put(i+"", v);
    }


    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myPath/Libro.csv"))) {
        int i=0;
        for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) !=null ; ) {
            if(i==0){
                i++;
            }
            else{
            String[] vertices = line.split(",");
            String vertex1 = vertices[0];
            String vertex2 = vertices[2];
            String weight= vertices[1];
            vertex2 = vertex2.replaceAll(" ", "");

            Vertex v1 = nodes.get(vertex1);
            Vertex v2 = nodes.get(vertex2);

            System.out.println("vertex v1 = " + v1);
            System.out.println("vertex v2 = " + v2);

            Edge eLives = orientDBGraph.addEdge(null, v1, v2, "connected");
            eLives.setProperty("weight", weight);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and I got

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I do not think it's that. Done what you told me also modify the file but still the same error, also have declared as String values so should not give me problems with the first line.

Comment: It is the first time I use this forum to ask questions, I had used before but only to see similar problems. Thank you very much for your help, now I understand why there are so many people in this forum, not how to thank you helped me a lot. Once again, thank you so much Alessandro

Comment: I had the error, because in my file (Libro.csv) the first node was 0 so it loaded as null only change for boot from 0 and solved, thanks without your help it would not have made.